# Extending JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, inheritance, jcombobox, extends

I am having trouble extending JComboBox. Mainly, I want to add a method that returns the selected Item into String. But since I might want to add more methods later on, I decided it would be better to create a child class.

```
import javax.swing.JComboBox;

public class ComboBox extends JComboBox{
    
    
    public ComboBox(Integer[] items) {
        super();
    }
    
    public ComboBox(String[] items) {
        super();
    }

    public String getSelectedItemInString() {
        return super.getSelectedItem().toString();
    }

}
```

Above is my attempt but it wouldn't work this way. It would only create ComboBoxes that look like this, and I am not able to see the items even if I click on the drop down button [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cwvlc.png)

I want to be able to create ComboBox that could take in both String[] or Integer[] in different instances.. just like how JComboBox allows to do this:

```java
String [] groups = {null, "Zombies","Instigators","Fantastic Beasts","Stranger Things"};
JComboBox<String> groupSelector = new JComboBox<String>(groups);

totalNum = new JComboBox<Integer>();
totalNum.addItem(null);
totalNum.addItem(0); totalNum.addItem(1);
totalNum.addItem(2); totalNum.addItem(3);
totalNum.addItem(4);
```

Comment: don't extend concrete JComponents (nor other classes) if you can reach the same by configuration.

Comment: @kleopatra what do you mean? I'm really new to Java (and software development in general) so you really have to elaborate for me. What do you mean by I can reach by configuration?

Comment: _I'm really new to Java (and software development in general)_ all the more reason not to _extend_ a class that's meant for _using_ (as all concrete JComponents). First learn to use the available api to get your work done, only if that's not possible think about how you could enhance the __functionality__ (vs adding cover methods with minimal variation).

Comment: if you insist on extending: JComboBox is generified - extending the raw (== Object) type and then constructors for every type you want to have in it is plain wrong. Instead, extend with the same generics as super: `class MyCombo<E> extends JComboBox<E>`.

Comment: a couple of comments, in no particular order: 1/ do not name custom classes the same as framework/jdk classes (ComboBox is the awt ancestor) 2/ do not override toString for application reasons 3/ beware: selectedItem might be null in which case your custom method will throw an NPE. Happy learning :)

Answer (score 1):

The array that you are passing into the constructor of your ComboBox-class needs to be passed on to the constructor of the JComboBox.

```
public ComboBox(E[] items) {
        super(items);
    }
```

The reason your code is not throwing an error is because JComboBox also has another constructor which does not require any parameters (you are currently calling the constructor https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#JComboBox() but want to call [https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#JComboBox(E[])](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#JComboBox(E%5B%5D))). However, you want to call the constructor which takes an Array as the parameter. That's why you have to pass the parameter on to the super()-methid you're calling.

Comment: @kleopatra I agree, didn't think about that. You can just refer to the documentation I linked above and use the same data types which will then enable you to pass Lists of Integers, Strings, Longs and whatever

Comment: thanks for fixing the snippet :)

Comment: @kleopatra Thanks for making me aware of it :)